# Converting a list of objects to a list of optional objects in Java

Tags: java, java-8

The following code converts a list of objects into a list of optional objects. Is there an elegant way to do this using Java 8's streams?

```
List<Object> originalList = Arrays.asList(new Object(), new Object());
List<Optional<Object>> convertedList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object object : originalList) {
    convertedList.add(Optional.of(object));
}
```

I tried the following piece of code.

```
List<Optional<Object>> convertedList = originalList.stream().map((o) -> Optional.of(o));
```

However this gives the following compile error:

```
of(T) in Optional cannot be applied to (java.lang.Object)
```

This is using the java.util.Optional class rather than the Guava one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot to collect the elements of the `Stream` in a list. It should be:

```
List<Optional<Object>> convertedList  = originalList.stream()
                                                    .map((o) -> Optional.of(o))
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
                                               //or .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new)); if you want a specific List implementation
```

Note that you could avoid the creation of a lamdba and use a method reference in this case with `.map(Optional::of)`.

I don't see why you would get a `List` of `Optional` if you know in advance that the elements in the list are non-null. Maybe it was just to get in practice with Java 8, but as @Eran said you should use `Optional::ofNullable` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I cut down the code for the purposes of the example. The convertedList will have absent values added to it after this in my use case and the originalList does not contain nulls.

Comment: While I would recommend the method ref form over the lambda form, don't fool yourself that you are "avoiding creation of a lambda" by using the method reference form.  Method refs are converted to functional interfaces via the same machinery as lambdas.  But, these decisions should be made on the basis of code readability/maintainability 99.999% of the time, so you should just go with what is more readable -- which is generally the method ref.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you forgot to collect the Stream to a list :

```
List<Optional<Object>> convertedList = 
    originalList.stream()
                .map((o) -> Optional.ofNullable(o))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You should use `ofNullable` though, since `of` required a non null object (it will throw a `NullPointerException` when passed a null reference).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's a good point about the ofNullable method, however in this case I know my list doesn't contain nulls - its only after this piece of code that I will add absent values to the new list.